# Ghostscript output bookmark empty string after PDF to PNG convert

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I convert PDF to PNG but Ghostscript replaces `ğ` and `ş` chars with empty strings.

The bookmark content is:

> *"Bu belge, 5070 sayılı Elektronik Imza Kanununun 5. maddesi gereğince güvenli elektronik imza ile imzalanmıştır."*

After the conversion the result is:

> *"Bu belge, 5070 sayılı Elektronik Imza Kanununun 5. maddesi gere ince güvenli elektronik imza ile imzalanmı tır."*

The Ghostscript parameters were :

```
  C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin>  gswin64c.exe -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH \
      -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dNumRenderingThreads=1 \
      -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
      -sDEVICE=png16m -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -r96 -dShowAnnots=false \
      -sOutputFile="out.png" -dShowAcroForm=true "in.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that the PDF has a missing font, and Ghostscript substitutes a font for the missing one. Unsurprisingly unusual glyphs may well not be present in the substitute font, or may not be at the same positions.

Try setting -dRENDERTTNOTDEF on the command line. If the missing glyphs are replaced with squares, then the problem is that the font being used doesn't have the required glyph in it. (Notdef = not defined)

Of course, this is all supposition since you haven't supplied the PDF file to look at, and haven't quoted the back channel output from GS.

Comment: i try -dRENDERTTNOTDEF  param but not resolve it.again it convert ŞĞÇÖÜ chars to empty string

Comment: The missing content is in fact an annotation, the annotation uses Times-Roman, which it re-encodes with a custom Encoding, but it does **not** embed the font. The version of Times-Roman supplied with GS does not have (among others) the /gbreve glyph, and so the PostScript /.notdef glyph is drawn, which is an empty glyph. The moral of the story is; embed the fonts you want to use.

Comment: I haven't seen the file, but if custom Encoding is in fact standard "latin5" (turkish?), missing font can be replaced through `fontmap` file.

Comment: The custom encoding isn't terribly relevant, its the fact that the font isn't embedded, so a substitute is required, and the supplied substitute simply doesn't have the glyph coverage required. It is, of course, possible to use a different substitute font, Acrobat use4s TimesNewRomanPSMT on my system.